# Fatal error: Call to a member function getObject() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, fatal-error

I'm making a Social Networking Website using this book called PHP5 Social Networking. 
I'm trying to edit the profile but I get this error

**Fatal error: Call to a member function getObject() on a non-object which is referring to this following line;**

```
if ( $registry->getObject('authenticate')->isLoggedIn() 
 && ( $registry->getObject('authenticate')->getUser()->getUserID() == $this->id 
   || $registry->getObject('authenticate')->getUser()->isAdmin() == true ) )
```

I'm a newbie to PHP so any help would be appreciated greatly.

This is the entire file;

```
<?php

/**
 * Profile model
 */
class Profile{

    /**
     * The registry
     */
    private $registry;

    /**
     * Profile ID
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * Fields which can be saved by the save() method
     */
    private $savable_profile_fields = array( 'name', 'hometown', 'university', 'gender', 'photo', 'bio', 'dob' );

    /**
     * Users ID
     */
    private $user_id;

    /**
     * Users name
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * Users hometown
     */
    private $hometown;

    /**
     * Users University 
     */
    private $university;

    /**
     * Users genders
     */
    private $gender;

    /**
     * Users bio
     */
    private $bio;

    /**
     * Users dob
     */
    private $dob;

    /**
     * Users photograph
     */
    private $photo;

    private $valid;

    /**
     * Profile constructor
     * @param Registry $registry the registry
     * @param int $id the profile ID
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct( Registry $registry, $id=0 )
    {
        $this->registry = $registry;
        if( $id != 0 )
        {
            $this->id = $id;
            // if an ID is passed, populate based off that
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM profile WHERE user_id=" . $this->id;
            $this->registry->getObject('db')->executeQuery( $sql );
            if( $this->registry->getObject('db')->numRows() == 1 )
            {
                $this->valid = true;

                $data = $this->registry->getObject('db')->getRows();
                // populate our fields
                foreach( $data as $key => $value )
                {
                    $this->$key = $value;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $this->valid = false;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            $this->valid = false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Is the profile valid
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isValid()
    {
        return $this->valid;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the users name
     * @param String $name
     * @return void
     */
    public function setName( $name )
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }


    /** 
    * Sets the users university 
    $@param String $university 
    */
    public function setUniversity( $university )
    {
        $this->university = $university;

    }


    /**
     * Set the users date of birth
     * @param String $dob the date of birth
     * @param boolean $formatted - indicates if the controller has formatted the dob, or if we need to do it here
     */
    public function setDOB( $dob, $formatted=true )
    {
        if( $formatted == true )
        {
            $this->dob = $dob;
        }
        else
        {
            $temp = explode('/', $dob );
            $this->dob = $temp[2].'-'.$temp[1].'-'.$temp[0];
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets the hometown of users
     * @param String $hometown
     * return void
     */
    public function setHometown( $hometown )
    {
        $this->hometown = $hometown;
    }

    /**
     * Set the gender of the user
     * @param String $gender the gender
     * @param boolean $checked - indicates if the controller has validated the gender, or if we need to do it
     * @return void
     */
    public function setGender( $gender, $checked=true )
    {
        if( $checked == true )
        {
            $this->gender = $gender;
        }
        else
        {
            $genders = array();
            if( in_array( $gender, $genders ) )
            {
                $this->gender = $gender;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets the users bio
     * @param String bio
     * @return void
     */
    public function setBio( $bio )
    {
        $this->bio = $bio;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the users profile picture
     * @param String photo name
     * @return void
     */
    public function setPhoto( $photo )
    {
        $this->photo = $photo;
    }

    /**
     * Save the user profile
     * @return bool
     */
    public function save()
    {
        // handle the updating of a profile
        if( $registry->getObject('authenticate')->isLoggedIn() && ( $registry->getObject('authenticate')->getUser()->getUserID() ==  $this->id || $registry->getObject('authenticate')->getUser()->isAdmin() == true  ) )


        {
            // we are either the user whose profile this is, or we are the administrator
            $changes = array();
            foreach( $this->saveable_profile_fields as $field )
            {
                $changes[ $field ] = $this->$field;
            }
            $this->registry->getObject('db')->updateRecords( 'profile', $changes, 'user_id=' . $this->id );
            if( $this->registry->getObject('db')->affectedRows() == 1 )
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Convert the users profile data to template tags
     * @param String $prefix prefix for the template tags
     * @return void
     */
    public function toTags( $prefix='' )
    {
        foreach( $this as $field => $data )
        {
            if( ! is_object( $data ) && ! is_array( $data ) )
            {
                $this->registry->getObject('template')->getPage()->addTag( $prefix.$field, $data );
            }
        }
    }



    /**
     * Return the users data
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray( $prefix='' )
    {
        $r = array();
        foreach( $this as $field => $data )
        {
            if( ! is_object( $data ) && ! is_array( $data ) )
            {
                $r[ $field ] = $data;
            }
        }
        return $r;
    }

    /**
     * Get the users name
     * @return String
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }


    /**
     * Get the users photograph
     * @return String
     */
    public function getPhoto()
    {
        return $this->photo;
    }

    /**
     * Get the users ID
     * @return int
     */
    public function getID()
    {
        return $this->user_id;
    }

}


?>

It also needs to pass through;
profileinformationcontroller.php

<?php

/**
 * Profile information controller
 */
class Profileinformationcontroller {

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param Registry $registry
     * @param int $user the user id
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct( $registry, $directCall=true, $user )
    {
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $urlBits = $this->registry->getObject('url')->getURLBits();
        if( isset( $urlBits[3] ) )
        {
            switch( $urlBits[3] )
            {
                case 'edit':
                    $this->editProfile();
                    break;
                default:
                    $this->viewProfile( $user );
                    break;
            }   
        }
        else
        {
            $this->viewProfile( $user );
        }

    }

    /**
     * View a users profile information 
     * @param int $user the user id
     * @return void
     */
    private function viewProfile( $user )
    {
        // load the template
        $this->registry->getObject('template')->buildFromTemplates( 'header.tpl.php', 'profile/information/view.tpl.php', 'footer.tpl.php' );
        // get all the profile information, and send it to the template
        require_once( FRAMEWORK_PATH . 'models/profile.php' );
        $profile = new Profile( $this->registry, $user );
        $profile->toTags( 'p_' ); 
    }

/**
 * Edit your profile
 * @return void
 */
private function editProfile()
{
    if( $this->registry->getObject('authenticate')->isLoggedIn() == true )
    {
        $user = $this->registry->getObject('authenticate')->getUser()->getUserID();
        if( isset( $_POST ) && count( $_POST ) > 0 )
        {
                    require_once( FRAMEWORK_PATH . 'models/profile.php' );

            // edit form submitted
            $profile = new Profile( $this->registry, $user );
            $profile->setName( $this->registry->getObject('db')->sanitizeData( $_POST['name'] ) );
            $profile->setHometown( $this->registry->getObject('db')->sanitizeData( $_POST['hometown'] ) );
            $profile->setUniversity( $this->registry->getObject('db')->sanitizeData( $_POST['university'] ) );
            $profile->setGender( $this->registry->getObject('db')->sanitizeData( $_POST['gender'] ), false );
            $profile->setBio( $this->registry->getObject('db')->sanitizeData( $_POST['bio'] ) );
            $profile->setDOB( $this->registry->getObject('db')->sanitizeData( $_POST['dob'] ), false );
            if( isset( $_POST['profile_picture'] ) )
            {
                require_once( FRAMEWORK_PATH . 'lib/images/imagemanager.class.php' );
                $im = new Imagemanager();
                $im->loadFromPost( 'profile_picture', $this->registry->getSetting('uploads_path') .'profile/', time() );
                if( $im == true )
                {
                    $im->resizeScaleHeight( 150 );
                    $im->save( $this->registry->getSetting('uploads_path') .'profile/' . $im->getName() );
                    $profile->setPhoto( $im->getName() );
                }
            }
            $profile->save();
            $this->registry->redirectUser( array('profile', 'view', 'edit' ), 'Profile saved', 'The changes to your profile have been saved', false );
        }
        else
        {
            // show the edit form
            $this->registry->getObject('template')->buildFromTemplates( 'header.tpl.php', 'profile/information/edit.tpl.php', 'footer.tpl.php' );
            // get the profile information to pre-populate the form fields
            require_once( FRAMEWORK_PATH . 'models/profile.php' );
            $profile = new Profile( $this->registry, $user );
            $profile->toTags( 'p_' ); 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $this->registry->errorPage('Please login', 'You need to be logged in to edit your profile');
    }
}

}


?>
```

Is there anyone who can help???
I'll send the source code to your email as well if it helps at all?

Thanks in advance  :)

Comment: How are you instantiating the `Profile` object? From its constructor, it takes two parameters, a `Registry` object and an id. `$prof = new Profile($registry, $id);`

Comment: is the space in `$registry-  >getObject('authenticate')->getUser()` a copy and paste mistake?

Comment: this happens because you are trying to invoke a method on something that's supposed to be an object, but it either isn't initialized yet (`NULL` value) or it's a primitive type. first check if what jaitsu said above is right

Comment: `$registry` has, probably, no value or is not of the object type that you expected. with `if ($registery == null)` you could test whether it is null or do `var_dump($registery)` to see what is in the registery variable.

Comment: Look at the Related Section to the right. What do you see? Tons of other questions all asking the same. Go through those to understand why you get that error. Then fix your code.

Comment: @Gordan yes Ive read through so many of these for the past week and clearly don't understand whats going on. I'm using a book that I brought from Amazon PHP5 Social Networking. I'm new at PHP so my knowledge and understanding is limited without some sort of direction. Just need some help really? Its for my final year project at University, I've sent emails to a few teachers but as per usual emails get ignored when students ask for help. Its more like go on to google and you'll find everything.

Comment: The error basically means: You're calling a member function but not object is there. That's basically calling a function that does not exists. In short: You made an error, fix it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not reference the object property `$registry` that you want to access, but an undefined local variable `$registry`. Change the line to this:

```
if( $this->registry->getObject('authenticate')->isLoggedIn() && ( $this->registry->getObject('authenticate')->getUser()->getUserID() ==  $this->id || $this->registry->getObject('authenticate')->getUser()->isAdmin() == true  ) )
```

...*or* add this line above your existing one:

```
$registry = $this->registry;
```

I would go for the first option but realistically it makes little/no difference.

Comment: I tried what you mentioned above, but this led me this the following error...

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/unilink2/models/profile.php on line 221

Fatal error: Error executing query: UPDATE profile SET WHERE user_id=3 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE user_id=3' at line 1 in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/unilink2/registry/mysqldb.class.php on line 242

Comment: which refers to this line
 public function executeQuery( $queryStr )
    {
     if( !$result = $this->connections[$this->activeConnection]->query( $queryStr ) )
     {
      trigger_error('Error executing query: ' . $queryStr .' - '.$this->connections[$this->activeConnection]->error, E_USER_ERROR);
  }
  else
  {
   $this->last = $result;
  }
  
    }
but I suppose the error is in this part of the code...

Comment: public function updateRecords( $table, $changes, $condition )
    {
     $update = "UPDATE " . $table . " SET ";
     foreach( $changes as $field => $value )
     {
      $update .= "`" . $field . "`='{$value}',";
     }
         
     // remove our trailing ,
     $update = substr($update, 0, -1);
     if( $condition != '' )
     {
      $update .= "WHERE " . $condition;
     }
     $this->executeQuery( $update );
     
     return true;
     
    }

Comment: @user1165028 Your problem there is simply a mis-spelling. When you define the property at the top of the class, it is called `$savable_profile_fields`, but when you pass it to the `foreach` it is called `$this->saveable_profile_fields` - note the extra `e` in `saveable`. You need to rename one or the other so that they match...

Comment: Random your a legend, I can't believe I didn't spot that I mean I looked at many times but I guess I overlooked it. Again I really appreciate your help.